# numpy sort 2d: rearrange rows without changing values in row

Tags: python, numpy

How can the  rows in an array be sorted  without  that the  values in each row will changed?
Furthermore: how  to get  the  indicies of this sort-process?

input:

```
a = np.array([[4,3],[0,3],[3,0],[1,3],[1,2],[2,0]])
```

required sorting arrray:

```
b = np.array([1,4,3,5,2,0])
a = a[b]
```

output:

```
a = np.array([[0,3],[1,2],[1,3][2,0],[3,0],[4,3]])
```

How do I get the array `b` ?

Comment: Get `b` from what? What are the inputs?

Comment: I have only found this,  where  I can sort accoring  to the first  value;  but  then the second  value  is not  taken care fore  and   i dont have  the sorting-array   a[a[:,1].argsort()]

Comment: "a"  are the input  values;   I try  to find out  how to get  the  array  "b"

Comment: IIUC, think you could put it as : `ab = a[b]` and then say how to get `b` from `ab` and `a`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [**`lexsort`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.lexsort.html) here:

```
b = np.lexsort((a[:, 1], a[:, 0]))
# array([1, 4, 3, 5, 2, 0], dtype=int64)
```

And applied to your initial array:

```
>>> a[b]
array([[0, 3],
       [1, 2],
       [1, 3],
       [2, 0],
       [3, 0],
       [4, 3]])
```

As @miradulo pointed out, you may also use:

```
b = np.lexsort(np.fliplr(a).T)
```

Which is less verbose than explicitly stating the columns to sort on.

Comment: That is the first line in my answer, `lexsort` gives you the sorted indices

Comment: Or `np.lexsort(np.fliplr(a).T)`, can be handy.

Comment: Oh that's very useful, especially as the number of columns grows