# how to sort complex structured data with numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a file whose lines consist of 2 integers and one float.
I read the file with numpy:

```html
dt = np.dtype([('pre', np.dtype('i4'), 2),('data', np.float64, 1)])
a = np.fromfile("myfile", dtype=dt)
```

```html
array([([65536, 65536], 0.2       ), ([65536,     1], 1.33566434),
       ([65536,     2], 2.06068931), ..., ([65535,   479], 0.33333333),
       ([65535,  2295], 0.09090909), ([65535,   249], 0.07692308)],
      dtype=[('pre', '<i4', (2,)), ('data', '<f8')])
```

I actually have two questions:
When I iterate a with np.nditer I can't access a[0][0][0] for example
Why is that and how to use np.nditer ?
Second question: How can I sort the elements after the first entry in the ['pre'] list and then after the second entry in ['pre']
The wanted output would look like:

```html
array([([1, 1], 0.2       ), ([1,     2], 1.33566434),
       ([1,     3], 2.06068931), ..., ([2,   1], 0.33333333),
       ([2,  2], 0.09090909), ([2,   3], 0.07692308)],
      dtype=[('pre', '<i4', (2,)), ('data', '<f8')])
```

Any suggestions are welcome, even if changing the data type for reading the file would help. Performance is needed as well because the file I have is very large.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a 1d structured array:

```
In [56]: arr = np.array([([65536, 65536], 0.2       ), ([65536,     1], 1.3356
    ...: 6434),
    ...:        ([65536,     2], 2.06068931), ([65535,   479], 0.33333333),
    ...:        ([65535,  2295], 0.09090909), ([65535,   249], 0.07692308)],
    ...:       dtype=[('pre', '<i4', (2,)), ('data', '<f8')])
    ...:       
In [57]: arr
Out[57]: 
array([([65536, 65536], 0.2       ), ([65536,     1], 1.33566434),
       ([65536,     2], 2.06068931), ([65535,   479], 0.33333333),
       ([65535,  2295], 0.09090909), ([65535,   249], 0.07692308)],
      dtype=[('pre', '<i4', (2,)), ('data', '<f8')])
In [58]: arr.shape
Out[58]: (6,)
In [59]: arr.dtype
Out[59]: dtype([('pre', '<i4', (2,)), ('data', '<f8')])
In [60]: arr['pre']
Out[60]: 
array([[65536, 65536],
       [65536,     1],
       [65536,     2],
       [65535,   479],
       [65535,  2295],
       [65535,   249]], dtype=int32)
In [61]: arr['data']
Out[61]: 
array([0.2       , 1.33566434, 2.06068931, 0.33333333, 0.09090909,
       0.07692308])
```

It has 2 fields.  The `pre` field has 2 elements, so the `arr['pre']` is a 2d numeric array.

As a general rule you don't need to use `nditer` to iterate through an array.  It's useful when developing `cython` code, but isn't needed in Python code.

If you use `nditer` you get a () shape array with the original dtype:

```
In [70]: for x in np.nditer(arr):
    ...:     print(x)

([65536, 65536], 0.2)
([65536,     1], 1.33566434)
([65536,     2], 2.06068931)
([65535,   479], 0.33333333)
([65535,  2295], 0.09090909)
([65535,   249], 0.07692308)
```

The difference between that direct iteration is subtle.  The `type` in the `nditer` case is `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>`. In the direct iteration case `<class 'numpy.void'>`.

As for the sorting, it sounds like you want `np.lexsort` using the 2 columns of the 'pre' field:

```
In [76]: np.lexsort((arr['pre'][:,1], arr['pre'][:,0]))
Out[76]: array([5, 3, 4, 1, 2, 0])
In [77]: arr[_]
Out[77]: 
array([([65535,   249], 0.07692308), ([65535,   479], 0.33333333),
       ([65535,  2295], 0.09090909), ([65536,     1], 1.33566434),
       ([65536,     2], 2.06068931), ([65536, 65536], 0.2       )],
      dtype=[('pre', '<i4', (2,)), ('data', '<f8')])
```

A similar `lexsort` was just recommended for [numpy sort 2d: rearrange rows without changing values in row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51370327/numpy-sort-2d-rearrange-rows-without-changing-values-in-row)

Comment: But nditer is much faster than normal iteration and as I said the file is large therefore using nditer is necessary for the performance.

Comment: lexsort seems to deliver the wanted result, but it's extremely slow as well

Comment: Who said `nditer` is much faster?  Have you tested it?